# How do I properly scale the image size when img tag inside table?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a png grpahic with several icons on it. This project is targeting accessibility so rather than use divs with brackground-image and background positioning, the client would like img tags and alt attributes.  We're using Twitter bootstrap which sets `img{max-width: 100%;}` This image is rendered inside a table cell that has a 50px by 50px dimensions. The image is 329px by 100px. This make the image super tiny and also shows all the icons of course. I was thinking of using css clip and provide classes to show the piece of the graphic I want.  What is the correct approach here? I'm setting `td { position: relative;}` and `img { max-width: none; position: absolute; clip: rect(9px, 184px, 34px, 155px) }` It seems hacky to me to be doing it this way. Is there a better approach I could be using? I just want to leverage the screen readers features for images as well good html design principals.  My css (LESS syntax) looks like this

```
.tinytable img {
   max-width: none;
   background: red;
   &.onetime {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(9px, 184px, 34px, 155px);
    &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to use left and top etc... to position it correctly. I've found all this much easier using background-image and background position, but that doesn't seem to be as accessible.  Also we're trying to use sprites wherever possible. Is there a way to do what I want using background size, and background position. Clip seems unreliable to me for some reason, not too mention I can see the entire image block container when debugging in Chrome or Firefox. Anyone have any ideas here? I'm sure this is a fairly common problem.

Comment: That's pretty much the idea behind CSS sprites. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Could you please give us a jsfiddle to play with?